# AWS SQS SDK for php is failing silently

Tags: php, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm playing around with AWS SQS but for some reason, whatever method I try to execute, it fails. 
On a slightly related not, S3 via the PHP SDK does work.

Below a small script which works fine up to `$client->listQueues();`.
There it just fails. No error, no output in any log or whatever.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require __DIR__ . '/src/bootstrap.php';

use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;

$client = new SqsClient([
    'region' => getenv('AWS_SQS_REGION'),
    'version' => '2012-11-05', // getenv('AWS_SQS_VERSION')
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => getenv('AWS_SQS_CRED_KEY'),
        'secret' => getenv('AWS_SQS_CRED_SECRET'),
    ]
]);
try {
    $result = $client->listQueues();
    foreach ($result->get('QueueUrls') as $queueUrl) {
        echo "$queueUrl\n";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    print($e->getMessage());
}
echo "DONE";
```

Running this locally on Ubuntu with PHP7, AWS SDK compatibility-test.php passed.